# how to fix weird bumps that were added by cloud texture

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to model this little claypot, I'm kind of a newbie here, and whilst making a clay texture I added this cloud type texture, which happened to add little weird lumps on top ring of the pot, and i also seem unable to make the outer ring a bit thicker too :( Would appreciate if someone told me how to fix it. Also, got problems with the mesh made by using a grease pencil, it gets insside of the pot when applying scale, which also makes lumps weirder.[image: before applying scale][image: after applying sscale]
[image: what i mean by makind the outer ring thicker]
link for a file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QDcW5W3o1dQyU9gXVwXATvE7mE25CDik/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hit the wrench icon, you have a displace modifier on the object that is producing the lumpiness based on the cloud texture.

Comment: @AllenSimpson questioner already acknowledges this.  Or maybe he edited to include this fact.  What do you think about my answer using V-groups or Weight-Painting?  Perhaps there's even better?

Comment: @james_t Ah, missed that.  I live in the shader editor, but it seems like a fine solution to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be other precise methods, as this one eliminates some of the "artisan imprecision" (displacement, distortion) you would be looking for around the top.   Assign most of the vertices to a vertex group:

[image: a wireframe pot in with the text "Assign all verts into a new v-group, except for a few around the top. An arrow points to the rim of the pot]

And then use this group in the Vertex Group field so that these edges aren't included in the Texture displacement:

[image: a menu showing the new vertex group selected. A note says: improvement in look when using "rest of vertices"]

I think this is at least better than a half solution.  You can try either of 2 V-groups. Also, you may find that *Weight Painting* or weighting LT 1.0 as you assign vertices closer to the top, may improve the subtle result you are hoping for.

Here is my solution [image]

Comment: oh my god thank you so much!

Comment: any ideas on how to make the grease drawing wrap around the pot?..

Comment: @bathroomenjoyer I missed this as you asked a 2-part Q and should probably post this as a separate Q as this is a common problem with multi-part Qs.  I'm not a grease user so cannot help you on that one.  If you could use the Check-mark at the top of my answer my reputation increases, thanks.